# Cannot install pathos after download

Tags: anaconda

I am attempting to run a script that uses pathos.multiprocessing. I could not find it in "All" packages for the relevant environment in Anaconda Navigator and so opened a Terminal Window from Navigator. I then typed:

```
pip install pathos
```

Which returned the message "Successfully installed". I still could not see the package in the list of packages for that environment and thus believed I have only downloaded, not installed the package. So I then ran, again from the same Navigator Terminal Window;

```
conda install pathos
```

Which returned the error

```
The following packages are not available from current channels: pathos
```

I do not understand as I thought I had already successfully downloaded using my pip install command. What is the error in my approach?

Comment: Did you try `conda install pathos` (without parentheses)?

Comment: Thank you that worked. I have hit a different error; Question edited.

Comment: What channels is it showing? Can you post the full error?

Comment: The `pip install pathos` should have worked fine. For Conda, you'll need `conda-forge` channel: `conda install -c conda-forge pathos`